# How can I assign an event to a button using the event method name as a string?

Tags: c#, events

I have a button and want to programatically add an event to it. The event method is already present in my class, and I want to use a string ("Button_Click") to assign the event to the button. I know this is possibe with methods, but is it possible with events?

I've tried some code so far (don't know if I'm on the right path though):

```
Type thisType = this.GetType();
EventInfo myEvent= thisType.GetEvent("Button_Click");
myEvent.AddEventHandler(this, null);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you want to add the event handler to a button.
In that case your code could be

```
// Get the info for the button type
Type thisType = theButton.GetType();

// The event to link to the event handler is the Click event
EventInfo handler = thisType.GetEvent("Click");

// Add the named method (Button_Click) as the event handler 
// for theButton Click event
handler.AddEventHandler(b, 
     Delegate.CreateDelegate(handler.EventHandlerType, this, "Button_Click"));
```

You can find more info on this QA
[How to attach event handler to an event using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120422/how-to-attach-event-handler-to-an-event-using-reflection)